# What's the secret to the purple room with four blocks and tetromino pictures on each side?

Tags: fez

It's a purple room with four blocks and a tetromino picture on each side (four): two upside-down Ts and two Ls. You can get to this area by going through the door atop the bell and entering the purple door on the opposite side. The stage is 3x3 with four blocks.

Answer (score 3):

**You need to push the blocks into the pink spots to form the tetromino shown on each side.**

The easiest method is stacking two blocks and pushing that stack into position from all perspectives. Then fill in the last two blocks. It'll turn into an anticube.

[image: stacked two high]
[image: still stacked two high]
[image: filling in the rest]
[image: anticube]

Comment: Any idea if this puzzle is glitchy on the PC version ?  It seems like the blocks won't align: the 3 first blocks always take 3 different lines, avoiding to be aligned...

Comment: @Anto: Not that I've heard. You want it to look my third picture and it'll animate to align like the pictured tetromino.

Answer (score -1):

Arrange the blocks into the tetris block shape so that it matches in both directions.

One is an L and the other an upside down T, so you can represent both shapes with just 4 blocks from different directions.